# Greatest $n<1000$ such that $\left \lfloor{\sqrt{n}}\right \rfloor-2 \mid n-4$ and $\left \lfloor{\sqrt{n}}\right \rfloor+2 \mid n+4$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

My first attempt was incorrect, and it is supposed to be a middle school problem.

So, if $n=k^2$

Then $k-2 \mid n-4$ and $k+2 \mid n+4$, so $n-4 \mid (n-4)(n+4)$. I then assumed the answer would be a perfect square  (not a great assumption) to get $n=961=31^2$. I then reasoned that $n$ would be around this value, so I checked these numbers and I think it was $958$. Is there a better way to do this, rather than just checking values less than $1000$?

Comment: Perhaps I do not understand your comment. It's assumed in the problem that $k+2$ would divide $k^2+4$.

Comment: Oh, no I didn't think that I was just trying something to get a bound on it. I don't think the logic is clear in my solution. It was just a hunch, and it got me pretty close, maybe by luck. If I'm not mistaken, there are almost no solutions for perfect squares? Do you know of a systematic way to do this?

Comment: Ok. Sorry. Deleting the earlier comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $k=[\sqrt n]$. Then we know that 
$$
k^2\le n<k^2+2k+1.
$$
So $n-4$ is in the range $[k^2-4,k^2+2k-4]$. Of the numbers in that range
only $k^2-4$, $k^2+k-6$ and $k^2+2k-8$ are divisible by $k-2$, so $n$ has to be one of $k^2,k^2+k-2, k^2+2k-4$.

We also see that $n+4$ is in the range $[k^2+4,k^2+2k+4]$. Of those numbers only
$k^2+k-2$ and $k^2+2k$ are divisible by $k+2$. Therefore $n$ also needs to be one of $k^2+k-6$, $k^2+2k-4$.

Looks like $n=k^2+2k-4=(k+1)^2-5$ is the only remaining alternative.

Therefore the answer is ____

Comment: Very nice! $(30+1)^2-5$!

Answer (score 1):

The numbers $n^2,n^2+1,n^2+2,.....,n^2+2n$ are such that the integer part of its square roots are the same and equal to $n$. It follows that we are concerned with the numbers $$31^2 and\space 961,962,.....,999\\30^2 and\space 900,901,.....,960\\29^2 and\space 841,842,.....,899\\.....\\.....$$
For $31^2 and\space 961,962,.....,999$ one has $29$ and $33$ to be computed so $29\cdot34=986$ is the only number to be considered; for $30^2 and\space 900,901,.....,960$ one has $28$ and $32$ and the numbers $924$ and $952$ to be considered; these numbers as well as the first,which is $864$, to be considered for $29^2$ does not give a solution. But the second number, the number $891$ gives the solution. In fact

$$\left \lfloor{\sqrt{895}}\right \rfloor-2 \mid 895-4\iff 891=27\cdot33\\\left \lfloor{\sqrt{895}}\right \rfloor+2 \mid 895+4\iff 899=29\cdot31$$

Comment: I think not. However maybe i have made a mistake when verify the number $956$. But I repeat, I think not. Regards.

Comment: $n=956$ works, because $952$ is divisible by $28$ and $960$ is divisible by $32$. The pattern of products that you want to look for is like $(k+4)(k-2)+4=k(k+2)-4$

Comment: So I have made a mistake when calculation with $956$. Thank you.